# SpriteKit: Making a character move in a world

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite, sprite-kit

i am trying to understand how you can make a huge world, and have a character move inside the world, and then it moves the visible part of the world with the moving character. Like the Mario game.

I read apples guide here: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH4-SW32

on "centering the scene on a node" but i really couldn't understand it at all. I tried implementing it, but it did not work at all.

So, anyone able to help me here? A full example with some good comments on would be great.

Hope my question makes sense, thanks on advance everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They try to talk with you "Your game world is a node and what you need to do only move the world node with your character". 
Game "Adventure" - the example game for Sprite Kit will help you a lot to create a huge world like that.

https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/AdventureArchitecture/AdventureArchitecture.html

=> There are example Code of this game in documentary.

Besides, you can create "Tile map" to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I use a simple class [AGMovingNode](https://github.com/andrew8712/AGMovingNode), inherited from `SKNode` as a background layer.

It's not perfect, but at least you can start from where.

Here is a code of the class:

**AGMovingNode.h**:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface AGMovingNode : SKNode

@property float pointsPerSecondSpeed;

- (instancetype)initWithPointsPerSecondSpeed:(float)pointsPerSecondSpeed;
- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime paused:(BOOL)paused;

@end
```

**AGMovingNode.m**:

```
#import "AGMovingNode.h"

@implementation AGMovingNode
{

    NSTimeInterval _lastUpdateTime;
    NSTimeInterval _deltaTime;

}

- (instancetype)initWithPointsPerSecondSpeed:(float)pointsPerSecondSpeed {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.pointsPerSecondSpeed = pointsPerSecondSpeed;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime paused:(BOOL)paused {
    if (paused) {
        _lastUpdateTime = 0;
        return;
    }
    //To compute velocity we need delta time to multiply by points per second
    if (_lastUpdateTime) {
        _deltaTime = currentTime - _lastUpdateTime;
    } else {
        _deltaTime = 0;
    }
    _lastUpdateTime = currentTime;

    CGPoint bgVelocity = CGPointMake(-self.pointsPerSecondSpeed, 0.0);
    CGPoint amtToMove = CGPointMake(bgVelocity.x * _deltaTime, bgVelocity.y * _deltaTime);
    self.position = CGPointMake(self.position.x+amtToMove.x, self.position.y+amtToMove.y);
}
@end
```

I found it in one of tutorials (can't remember which one right now) and slightly modified it.

Answer (score 0):

I found it best if you use SKActions to move objects around.

What i do is have a method to reposition my character also with sprite animations (when he is standing and when he is walking):

```
- (void)moveUser:(CGPoint)position {
  SKSpriteNode *user = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"userSprite"];

  // ... some logic to load correct atlas
  NSArray *animationFrames = ...

  SKAction *animation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:animationFrames timePerFrame:0.05f numberOfFrames:animationFrames.size];
  SKAction *moveToPositionAction = [SKAction moveTo:position duration:0.4f];

  [userNode runAction:[SKAction group:@[animation,moveToPositionAction]]];
}
```